# SQL Join with case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, case

i have these five tables

```
order_type(id,name)
order_stage_install(id,name)
order_stage_remove(id,name)
order_stage_redo(id,name)
orders(id,typeid,stageid)
```

i need to join orders table dynamically with these condition

```
    if order.typeid=1 
then join order_stage_install on order.stageid=order_stage_install.id
    if order.typeid=2 
then join order_stage_remove on order.stageid=order_stage_remove.id
```

i have tried that

```
    SELECT  *
FROM  orders o
            CASE 
            WHEN o.Type IN (1) THEN
             JOIN orders_stage os ON o.stageID=os.ID
            end
```

but it's giving me incorrect syntax near 'CASE' error
i have made a research about case statements and if statements in sql but no hope . any help appreciated

Comment: You can't use a case _expression_ to conditionally join different tables. Do LEFT JOIN instead.

Comment: Even i tfhere was some syntax that allowed you to do that (you could try dynamic sql), it would mean that for different values of `order.typeid` in different rows you would have different columns. This is, of course, impossible.

Comment: This is a faq. Please before considering posting read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: You don't say what you want to do. Giving meaningless code does not communicate your thoughts. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. When giving a business relation(ship)/association or table (base or query result), say what a row in it states about the business situation in terms of its column values. Please in code questions give a [mre]--including cut & paste & runnable minimal code & minimal representative data given as code. For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL, including constraints, indexes & tabular initialization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use LEFT JOIN and handle with COALESCE clause to handle NULL values coming from tables. E.g, If both order_install, order_remove can have OrderDetailname and one of them will give values, based on the typeId.

You need to have `COALESCE(order_install.OrderDetailName, order_remove.OrderDetailName)  AS OrderDetailName`

```sql
SELECT  o.*, -- COALESCE( You need to have COALESCE clause here to handle values coming from both tables
FROM  orders o
LEFT OUTER join order_stage_install on order.stageid=order_stage_install.id
AND o.typeId = 1
LEFT OUTER JOIN order_stage_remove  on order.stageid=order_stage_remove.id
AND o.typeId = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

as @Venkataraman_R mentioned , his solution has solved the problem
here is the full sql statment

```
SELECT  
COALESCE(osn.enum,osr.enum,osre.enum) as 'Current Stage',
COALESCE(oen.enum,oer.enum,oere.enum) as 'Current Phase',ot.enum as 'Order Type',
o.ID,scheduled_date as 'Scheduled'
  ,opened_date as 'Opened'
FROM  orders o
LEFT OUTER JOIN orders_types ot ON o.Type = ot.ID

LEFT OUTER join orders_stage osn  on o.stageID=osn.ID
AND o.Type = 1
LEFT OUTER JOIN orders_stage_removal osr  on o.stageID=osr.ID
AND o.Type = 2
LEFT OUTER JOIN orders_stage_redo osre  on o.stageID=osre.ID
AND o.Type = 3

LEFT OUTER join orders_enum_install oen  on o.enumID=oen.ID
AND o.Type = 1
LEFT OUTER JOIN orders_enum_removal oer  on o.enumID=oer.ID
AND o.Type = 2
LEFT OUTER JOIN orders_enum_redo oere  on o.enumID=oere.ID
AND o.Type = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

I know one should only answer a question. But in this case, it seems to be better to optimize the data structure first to avoid the JOINs at all.

The data structure seems to be not optimal, to say it gently.
That results subsequently in complicated JOIN strategies and a lot of other problems.

Please explain what the three order_stage_* - tables contain and shall do for you.

My guess is that you want to store those orders in those three tables that have a specific stage.
But that needs to be done with just one additional attribute on the table orders, in case those stages are disjunct (= always different, not possible that one order has multiple stages).